# Sublime 3 + Livereload on localhost (with sass running)

Tags: php, sass, localhost, sublimetext3, livereload

Im running my current project on **localhost** (via Terminal in Mac `php -S localhost:8888`)

I also use **SASS** and I would like to use **LiveReload** but it doesnt work for this project.

***It does work for simple html-files*** so the problem seem to be the local webserver. changes in php dont trigger LiveReload. Changes in .scss neighter ...

Anyone has got a clue whats the issue here? 
Im not hacker enough :/

Thaaaaanks, much love!

Comment: Your html file doesnt use SASS. It uses sass files converted to CSS. I assume you are referencing CSS in your html files for use on Livereload?

Comment: Thats a valid point. Yes, im my HTML (it comes from a php file though) CSS is referenced as .css meaning that either php or "localhost" is the problem ...